# Drupal System cron temporary file/folder error

Tags: cron, files

I have very specific problem which I can't resolve. Thing is, I've created few files with function that creates temporary files and then system cron after running should delete them. Problem that I have is that I have manually deleted (temporary) file named "user-upload" and then created folder which has exact same name. Now when system cron runs it gives me two errors:

> Could not delete temporary file "public:///user-upload" during garbage
>   collection public:///user-upload is a directory and cannot be removed
>   using file_unmanaged_delete().

I think I should somehow clear something in database but not exactly sure where to look at. Running drush cc all isn't helping in this case.

Thank you

---

EDIT: 
Eh, it takes you to ask question so you can get better idea. For the reference, solving this issue is locating particular file under database table "file_managed" column "filename" and then manually deleting it.
Maybe it will help someone...

Comment: Glad you figured it out - you should include that as an answer, and then accept that answer so it doesn't continue to show as an unanswered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reference, solving this issue is locating particular file under database table "file_managed" column "filename" and then manually deleting it.

Comment: if you delete it, then it will not be there in the linked nodes.

Comment: if you delete it, then will it be there in the linked nodes ?

Comment: Small workaround for this issue as start off with.    https://www.drupal.org/project/skip_temp_file_warnings I'm using the external storage it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a small workaround for this issue added as a module in drupal.org here

Enable and configure it in admin->configuration->Development->logging and errors

https://www.drupal.org/project/skip_temp_file_warnings

Answer (score 0):

Since playing with DB is not a good practice for basic users,as @Vladan mentioned:

1. Open your database from phpmyadmin
2. under database table "file_managed"
3. Check the box near every file with **status = 0**
4. Delete all files at once.
5. Run cron again